# Avoiding damage to phone screen

Tags: cell-phone

I don't know this is the correct platform to ask or not but I need help that how to protect your phone screen from damaging, as my phone protector always gets a crack, it really is a problem need your suggestions

Comment: Hi Laila, Welcome to Lifehacks. Do you have a case for your phone? What happened in the past (you said always)? Please edit your question to add details for someone to help you avoid the problem in the future.

Comment: You say the phone "protector" always gets a crack. Is that the phone screen itself, or something you place over it? If the latter, perhaps it is just doing its job and the screen itself has survived a knock.

Comment: It's the protector, i said always because I have changed 2 to 3 phones because of this issue,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used about 3 phones in last 6 years. The first one was a Nokia, whose screen I broke for 6 times; after that I used a HTC, broke the screen 2 times; currently I'm using a iPhone and have broken the screen 2 times.

Over time I have learnt that a good rubber cover is the best deal to protect the phone and screen. Buy one which has its edges coming a little bit over the bezel of phone, secondly, a hack is that just don’t use any phone protection, you will be automatically be more cautious with it.